# Share text clipboard, on demand only, between an iphone and mac laptop? Not using Continuity/Univeral Clipboard

Tags: iphone, mac, sharing, copy-paste

I'd like to have the option to `Share` my clipboard, **only when I ask for it**, between my MBP (Big Sur/osx 11) and my iphone (ios 14).

What I don't want to use is `Continuity/Handoff` as I found the constant notifications and sharing (of urls, clipboards, text messages even when I had iMessage turned off and logged out ...) really distracting and over the top.

Something that would `Airdrop` that clipboard on demand, even if I had to start another app is what I am looking for.

Not [Continuity/Universal Clipboard](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT209460)!  This is for text only, I can share urls and images other ways.

(For now, I tend to use Gmail drafts to do this, that's how low tech and low volume I am with this.)

Comment: I'm using two shortcuts on iOS to copy/paste text to a file in iCloud. On the Mac I just edit the file directly. It usually works and I only rarely have to wait for the system to sync.

Comment: Is this bidirectional, or strictly MBP > iPhone?

Comment: @IconDaemon ideally both ways.  For example, I was looking up my physiotherapists in my phone's contacts, where it only gives his name, so I am not even sure if it's actually this guy.  So, idea was to Google search for phone # on laptop and find his clinic first before calling.  There might be 1-2 sentences worth of text to copy over, at most.

Comment: @laktak Yes, guess I could do this too.  I even have a good text editor handy on iphone.  But it seems so low tech, just like my gmail drafts (which is more likely to work via cellular data without risking big bills too).  Frustrating there isn't something lightweight and unintrusive.

Comment: @JLPeyret You misunderstood. On the iPhone you use two Shortcuts - launch it from the widget so it's just one tap to either copy or paste.